# Refreshing fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, adapter

I have a fragment which doesn't contain anything at the application start, but after the data is loaded it should show the loaded data. I do all my data loading in MainActivity in function onDataLoaded which implements DataLoadedListener. After the data is loaded the function sends the data (ArrayList) as a parameter through the function call (initializeAdapter()). Then, the function initializeAdapter() gets it and initialize custom made adapter (adapter is a global object, initialized in initializeAdapter() and used in onCreateView()).

I guess that I should refresh fragment view after the data is loaded and the adapter is initialized, but I don't know how to do it. I tried in a lot of ways but didn't make it.

onDataLoaded function in MainActivity which calls initializeAdapter()

```
    @Override
    public void onDataLoaded(List<Grad> gradovi, List<Ponuda> ponude) {

    Spinner spinnerGradovi = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gradovi_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterGradovi;
    List<String> listaGradova = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Ponuda> ponudaArrayList = new ArrayList<Ponuda>();

    ponudaLista = ponude;
    gradLista = gradovi;

    for(Grad grad : gradovi ){
        listaGradova.add(grad.getNaziv());
    }

    for(Ponuda ponuda : ponude){
        ponudaArrayList.add(ponuda);
    }


    adapterGradovi = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listaGradova);

    spinnerGradovi.setAdapter(adapterGradovi);

    Fragment fragmentGet = svePonudeFragment;

    ((SvePonudeFragment)fragmentGet).initializeAdapter(ponudaArrayList);
}
```

and this is a Fragment

```
public class SvePonudeFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView rv;
RVAdapter adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sve_ponude_fragment, container, false);

    rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}


public void initializeAdapter(List<Ponuda> preuzetePonude){

    adapter = new RVAdapter(preuzetePonude);

    //this isn't working
    /*FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();*/

    //this is not working, neither
    Fragment frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("sve_ponude_fragment_tag");
    final android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(frg);
    ft.attach(frg);
    ft.commit();
}

}
```

I am also interested in how to make an empty adapter which loads if data is not loaded yet? And when the data is loaded to fill out another adapter and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize adapter before you set. If you interested to change you approach I can give suggestions: Create a constructor for you fragment which you can pass the ArrayList. OnCreate or OnCreateView you can initialize the adapter and pass the list into. After setting adapter notifyDataChanges and to check if there is data please use some Logs when you pass the data and before you pass the data. Do not directly blame the adapter or fragment control your data. Besides I suggest you to study more using fragments + RecyclerView. I am posting one example that you can look at but the data load in the fragment.

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

//Class Tag
private static final String TAG = CategoryFragment.class.getSimpleName();
//Fragments base context
private Context mContext;
//RecyclerView widget
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
//RecyclerView's Layout Manager
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayourManager;
//RecyclerView's Adapter
private CategoryFragmentAdapter mCategoryFragmentAdapter;
//Category Data List
private ArrayList<Category> mCategoryList;
//Interface object
onCategoryItemClick mCallBackCategory;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    //Instantiate base context
    mContext = context;
    //Instantiate interface
    mCallBackCategory = (onCategoryItemClick)getActivity();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Instantiate Category List
    mCategoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    //Custom fragment view instantiating
    View view_fragment_category = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container, false);
    //Instantiating Fragment's recycler view
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view_fragment_category.findViewById(R.id.recycle_categories);
    //Instantiate RecycleView's Layout Manager: LinearLayoutManager is one of the default
    mLayourManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    //Setting layout manager for recycler view
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayourManager);
    //Retrieve data from server, populate the category data list and set the RecyclerView's adapter
    getCategories();
    //Instantiate the adapter and push the data
    mCategoryFragmentAdapter = new CategoryFragmentAdapter(mContext, mCategoryList);

    //RecyclerView item click listener
    mCategoryFragmentAdapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new CategoryFragmentAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v , int position) {
            //Test display
            //Toast.makeText(mContext, mCategoryList.get(position).getId(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Push to Activity method with clicked item ID
            mCallBackCategory.proceedToProducts(mCategoryList.get(position).getId());

        }
    });

    return view_fragment_category;
}
```